# Eliminate arbitrary constants and form the differential equation of $y=Ae^{ax}+ Be^{bx}+Ce^{cx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the differential equation of 
$$y=Ae^{ax}+ Be^{bx}+Ce^{cx},$$
where $A, B, C$ are the arbitrary constants.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), see also [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial of this differential equation has roots $a,b,c$ and thus is $$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc,$$
corresponding to the differential equation
$$
y'''=(a+b+c)y''-(ab+bc+ca)y'+abcy.
$$

Comment: A small note: if $a,b,c$ are not distinct then there are simpler equations.